# Computing the Picard group of a ring from pushout square

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Define a locally invertible module over a ring $R$ as a module such that at every prime, the principal localization at some $f$ not in the prime is a free $R_f$ module.  Define the Picard group of a ring $R$ as the isomorphism classes of locally invertible $R$-modules.

> I am just trying to use a pushout square of rings to find the
>   Picard group of the ring $k[x,y]/(xy(x+y+1))$ , where $k$ is a field.

Here is the pushout square

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD} k[x,y]/(xy) @>>> k \oplus k \\ 
@AAA @AAA \\
 k[x,y]/(xy(x+y+1)) @>>> k[x,y]/(x+y+1) \end{CD}$$

and the Picard groups of all entries except the lower left ring is trivial.

The map to $k\oplus k$ is the map to $k[x,y]/(xy) \otimes k[x,y]/(x+y+1) \cong k[x,y]/(xy, x+y+1) \cong k[x]/(x(x+1)) \cong k \oplus k$

I thought of this because I saw something on conductor squares when I looked up Picard groups and I thought that maybe a pushout square like the one above might be able to accomplish the same thing accomplished using conductor squares in an easier way.

In other words I am trying to work by hand to compute the picard group of this ring without using conductors, just using the pushout square above.

---

edit:  I have edited my post above.

Comment: What is a conductor square? It seems like you're asking the following. Suppose that $X\to Y$ is a morphism and $Z\hookrightarrow Y$ is a closed embedding such that $X\times_Y Z$, $X$, and $Z$ have trivial Picard group. Does this imply that $Y$ has trivial Picard group. The answer is no. Let $X=\mathbb{P}^1$, let $Y=\text{Spec}(k[x,y]/(y^2-x^2(x+1))$ (the nodal cubic, and let $Z$ be the inclusion of the (reduced) point $(1,-1)$ and let $X\to Y$ be the normalization map. Then, $\text{Pic}(X)=0$, $\text{Pic}(Z)=0$, $X\times_Y Z\cong Z$ has trivial Picard group. But, $\text{Pic}(Y)\cong k^\times$.

Comment: Let me know if I answered your question--I'm actually not sure. :S

Comment: Well, is my interpretation of your question correct? That you're asking whether given a fibered diagram

$$\begin{matrix} X\times_Y Z & \to & X\\ \downarrow & & \downarrow\\ Z & \to & Y\end{matrix}$$

with $\text{Pic}(X\times_Y Z)=\text{Pic}(X)=\text{Pic}(Z)=0$ whether this implies that $\text{Pic}(Y)=0$? Because, if that's the correct interpretation, then it's not correct as my above example shows.

Comment: Yes it is.  Sorry for deleting my comment, earlier.  But you made me realize that I am asking the wrong question.  Can I use the pushout square to find out what the picard group is?  =

Comment: But, what does this mean? If you have a fibered diagram where all terms but one are zero, and the last is non-zero, how could you use the square to determine anything? What do you mean by 'determine' here?

Comment: I am going to abandon this approach.  I think I will try to use the definition of the picard group as isomorphism classes of line bundles on this variety and try to find the possible combinations of gluings on the intersections of the lines $x=0$, $y=0$ and $x=0, x+y+1=0$ and $y=0, y+x+1=0$.